# Проблема с заполнением contentvalues,происходит вставка в бд (SQLITE) пустых значений

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

Я реализовал метод,который добавляет значения в бд(SQLITE)

```
    public void addWrite(String key,String text) {

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(key,text );
            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
            database.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null,contentValues);
            contentValues.clear();

    }
```

Есть два activity у которых я получаю строки из edittext,значения этих строк я добавляю в метод используя в аргументах имя столбца и полученное значение у edittext.
Проблема в том что при каждом добавление строк в конкретный столбец,в другой столбец поступает пустое значение.Я попробовал уже много вариантов решения,но не один не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не понимаете основных принципов работы базы данных. Одна запись это запись строки в базу данных, то есть все столбцы должны быть заполнены. По умолчанию если вы значение не записываете в столбец, записывается NULL, если у таблицы есть внешние связи определённого типа, то и в других таблицах будет добавлена строка или более. Можно настроить что бы в столбец нельзя было записать NULL, но в таком случае запись не будет выполнена, а база данных вернёт ошибку, решается это установкой дефолтного значения, если значение туда не будет записываться, будет записываться дефольное значение. Почитайте основы, [например].[1](https://habr.com/ru/post/123636/)

А теперь о практике: что бы легче понимать представляйте одну строку как некий объект, а таблицу, как спискок этих объектов. С внешними связями сложнее, их не особо получится наложить на ООП. Второе: рекомендую вам, использовать [ORM](https://habr.com/ru/post/237889/), потому как для андроида редко нужно строить сложные таблицы, да и простые варианты вполне реализуются в ORM. Я пользуюсь: [Room](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html), раньше использовал [Realm](https://realm.io/), вторая конечно не особо ORM, но вполне удобна, в чёмто лучше Room, тут всё зависит от целей и задач.

Comment: realm совсем не ORM. это нереляционная база данных

Comment: @pavlofff, с вами не возможно не согласиться. Но тут конечно возможно и я заблуждаюсь в своих понятиях. Для меня ORM - это способ работы с реляционной базой данных придерживаясь концепций обьектно-ориентированных языков, Realm - это же система управления объектной базой данных. В итоге всё сводится к объектам, что бы разработчик мог придерживатся знакомых ему концепций. Спасибо, попробую разобраться в данных формулировках глубже.

Comment: да, вы правы. ORM (object relation map) - "надстройка" над реляционной базой, которая конвертирует данные из этой базы в объекты, но сама база остается реляционной, мы создаем таблицы, связи между ними и пишем SQL- запросы.Так, Room работает поверх SQLite. Realm изначально работает с объектами, в ней нет никаких таблиц, SQL- запросов, связывания по ключу и проч. свойственного реляционным базам и в основе ее такая база не лежит - поэтому realm  и совсем совсем не ORM